# os.path.dirname and os.path.join

Tags: python, os.path

```
modpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
datapath = os.path.join(modpath, '../../datas/orcl-1995-2014.txt')
```

I am really new to python... May I ask should I understand the codes as follow?

`modpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))`

means saving the name of the folder of the current location in absolute path format in the variable modpath? That means not the exact path leading to the current location but its folder?

`next,datapath = os.path.join(modpath, '../../datas/orcl-1995-2014.txt')`

means saving the join string of the path saved in modpath with the later string?

Comment: Yes, and yes...

Comment: The term "saving" is wrong here. The first line is: 1) computing the absolute path to the executable and 2) removing the filename (thus obtaining the absolute path to the directory that contains the executable). The second line is *concatenating* the path to this directory with the OS path separator plus the string `../../datas blah blha`

Comment: "The folder of the current location" is wrong. `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, not the current working directory. If the script is in the current directory then of course they are the same, but if you run `python ../script.py` then the result is the parent directory of the current directory, and if you run `python /path/to/script.py` then the result is `/path/to` which may or may not be entirely different from the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

### First, let's understand what each function do:

#### [`os.path.abspath(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)

Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path.

You used:

```py
os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
```

Example:

```py
>>> print(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
/usr/bin/ipython
```

Pathlib equivalent:

```py
>>> pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).resolve()
/usr/bin/ipython
```

#### [`os.path.dirname(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

Returns the directory name of `path`.

You used:

```py
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

Example:

```py
>>> os.path.dirname('/usr/bin/ipython')
/usr/bin
```

Pathlib equivalent:

```py
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0])
modpath = path.parent
```

#### [`os.path.join(path1, path2, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Joins one or more path components.

You used:

```py
os.path.join(modpath, '../../datas/orcl-1995-2014.txt')
```

Example:

```py
>>> print(os.path.join('/etc', 'dir1', '..', 'dir2', 'dir3/dir4'))
/etc/dir1/../dir2/dir3/dir4
```

Pathlib equivalent:

```py
datapath = modpath.parent.parent / 'datas' / 'orcl-1995-2014.txt'
```

### Now, let's follow the code:

1. Resolve [`sys.argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) - Which is the path to your Python script. Let's say it is `/usr/bin/python`.
2. Apply `os.path.abspath` on `/usr/bin/python` - You can try it in the interpreter. The result is `/usr/bin/python`, since it is already an absolute path.
3. Apply `os.path.dirname` on the result (`/usr/bin/python`). The result is the directory name of `usr/bin/python', which is`/usr/bin`. Save it in`modpath`.
4. Concatenate modpath (`/usr/bin/`) with `../../datas/orcl-1995-2014.txt` using `os.path.join` - which results in `/usr/bin/../../datas/orcl-1995-2014.txt`. Save it on `datapath`.

Answer (score 0):

**os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])** would return the absolute path.
**os.path.dirname(path)** function returns the head of the path.

**modpath** would be the head of path.

**os.path.join(path1, path2)** function would join two directory paths.

Hope this helps!